# How do I get my code to loop back to an input once it has been executed already? (RPG Game)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner at Python and thought it would be fun to code a text-based RPG game. It is by no means efficient, I'm just doing it for the fun of it.

I want my code to loop back to a specific decision path I have created where you can choose to do different actions. These actions are different subroutines that it calls depending on what you enter. However, I can't figure out how to get it to loop back once you have already chosen and completed an action.

Here is the code:

```
print("\n~DECISION PATH~\n\n[READ NOTICE BOARD][TALK TO WIZARD][TALK TO BLACKSMITH][TALK TO ARMOURER][VIEW STATS]")
action=input("\nWhat will you do? ")

if action == "Read notice board":
    noticeBoard()
elif action == "Talk to wizard":
    wizard()
elif action == "Talk to blacksmith":
    blacksmith()
elif action == "Talk to armourer":
    armourer()
elif action == "View stats":
    viewStats()
```

If somebody could help me out that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't encountered `while`?  As in `while True:`?  Also note that your users will shoot you if they have to get the capitalization exactly right every time, especially since your prompt has all upper case.  Perhaps you should convert `action = action.lower()` before checking.

Answer (score 0):

Add a while loop with condition = True if you want the user to play it again and again. You can add a condition such that exit the game if the user presses a key if you prefer that.

```
print("\n~DECISION PATH~\n\n[READ NOTICE BOARD][TALK TO WIZARD][TALK TO BLACKSMITH][TALK TO ARMOURER][VIEW STATS]")

while(True):
    action=input("\nWhat will you do? ")

    if action == "Read notice board":
        noticeBoard()
    elif action == "Talk to wizard":
        wizard()
    elif action == "Talk to blacksmith":
        blacksmith()
    elif action == "Talk to armourer":
        armourer()
    elif action == "View stats":
        viewStats()
```